# Flutter: ListView inside ListView don't scroll

Tags: android, listview, flutter, scroll

I want to nest a ListView inside a ListView.

Here's the code:

```
return ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
    itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
    itemPositionsListener: itemPositionListener,
    itemCount: widget.favouritesCategories.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return CategoryPublicationList(favouriteCategory: widget.favouritesCategories[index]);
    });
```

This ListView work fine but

```
return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: publications.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return PublicationWidget(publication: publications[index]);
      });
```

Insided ListView don't scroll.
Can somebody help me, please?

[image: UI I would like]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the inner `ListView` be scrollable independently of the main scroll view, you should use `NestedScrollView`.

Please check more info [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

it will not work, only 1 ListView will work, 
You can use SliverWidget, make a CustomScrollView and within that you can use nested scroll using SliverList.

https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-customscrollview-with-slivers-examples

Comment: A CustomScrollView where inside there is a SliverList and inside this SliverList the inner SliverList?

Comment: All SliverWidgets can be used only within CustomScrollView, can you UI what u want  to acheive

Comment: I've push an image, some idea? It's a list that for each item there is another list when you click